# Passing an NSFetchedResultsController as property to a Table View

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view with a fairly big list of suppliers. On selection, each row opens another table view with a list of employees for said supplier.

I was wondering if it was considered bad practice to pass on an NSFetchedResultsController as property to a second table view. Should I just pass in the necessary information to create the NSFetchedResultsController in the second view?

The reason I would like to pass on an NSFetchedResultsController is for reusability.

Thanks